# Ionic/Cordova - App only installing on nougat

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, apk

I have recently started using `ionic/cordova` and I am currently in the process of testing my app on different android platforms. In my config.xml file, I set my `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdk` to `19 (Kitkat)` and my `maxSdkVersion` to `26 (Oreo)` like so.

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="26" />
```

When I add my android platform this carries through into the AndroidManifest.xml like it supposed to. After I run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` and continue to sign the app as according to the deploying docs on the ionic site, I try installing the apk on different devices. It installs and works fine on nougat devices but on marshmallow and kitkat devices it doesn't install at all.

When I run `ionic cordova platform add android --save` it says:

> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0 Adding android
>   
> project... 
>   
> Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
>   
>          Path: platforms\android
>   
>          Package: io.ionic.starter
>   
>          Name: Lock_Ninja
>   
>          Activity: MainActivity
>   
>          Android target: android-26 
>   
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib

According to other forums the change made to the config.xml file is suppose to overwrite the Android Target shown above. But despite all this, the apk only installs on nougat devices. How can i fix this?

> ionic: version 3.19.0
>  cordova: 7.1.0
>  cordova-android@6.3.0
>   AndroidSdkBuildTols: 27.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/apk-only-installs-on-nougat-devices/118517/2?u=uvir127

Basically the package name of app was conflicting with an already installed app with the same name